# Why curl Couldn't resolve host intermittently?

Tags: php, web-services, curl, nginx, libcurl

I have a web service application that works fine in my local. I have even installed ngrok and I'm able to call it on the public web. But as I put my code on our production server I keep getting the 'Couldn't resolve host' error. I'm using different APIs in my service and intermittently I get this error. (I use apache in my local and nginx on prod)

For example I work with googleapis.com and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't on the server. The exact same code works just fine on my local.

It's worth mentioning that I've had this application for few months on this server and it's only this past few days that I've started to get these type of errors.

BTW I've noticed that the Curl version in my local and production and their settings are different but I don't know if that could be the source of the problem because it was working just fine.

I would appreciate any kind of guidance.

Comment: Try checking the name servers, they may be timing out, or limits. You may also want to consider adding a dns cache.